# Alternatives for accurately representing Visual Basic Decimal variables in C++

Tags: c++, vb.net

I am currently working on a program that takes Visual Basic data in the form of a text file, and then stores this data in C++.  Some of the data from Visual Basic is of the type Decimal.  C++ has no built in type equivalent to decimal.  I don't want to use double because there is a possible loss of significant figures if the numbers are large enough.

One option is write my own decimal class.  I was wondering if there were any other alternatives for solving this problem before I attempted to do that.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: If you use c++ cli you have access to all of the .net types is this an option

Answer (score 0):

There's the [decNumber](http://speleotrove.com/decimal/decnumber.html) library.  This is a C library designed for use with decimal numbers without losing precision/accuracy.

Given that it's a C library, you should be able to easily wrap it in a C++ class, or just use the C functions directly

This is an IBM sponsored lib and it's available under an open source license (ICU)

Answer (score 0):

Using a `Decimal` class is the best solution in my opinion. As to writing your own implementation, try a short web research first: It seems that others had the same problem before. The first Google result reveals a [CodeProject solution](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/decimalclass.aspx), there may be many other...